# Vertical align the bottom of an image and the top of some text

Tags: html, css

I want to align multiple images on a line with some text below every image. The text can have multiple lines and is aligned at the center. The images can have different heights but always the same width.
The bottom of the images should be at the same height and the top of the textboxes should be at the same height.

To better illustrate this:

[image]

Comment: I would think you could use tables for this. It feels like tabular data, not layout.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Tabular data?  It looks very much like layout to me...

Comment: @j08691 Yeah but got nothing of real value

Comment: The only tricky part with using a table would be aligning the bottom of the images. Naturally they would want to stay at the top. I might try finding the maximum height of the images through javascript then set the margin-top style attribute to each image by doing currImg.setAttribute('margin-top', maxImgHeight-currImg.height);

Comment: @Mike Obviously it's tricky to tell in this situation. We don't have much info to go off of. That's why I posted a comment and not an answer. That being said it's possible that the images and text are stored and retrieved from a database. Oskwish stated that they were related to each other and they're in rows and columns. Ultimately it depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **CSS** table layout to achieve this: (updated to a simplified version) [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xWA6d/4/embedded/result/)

The trick is to stick to `baseline` for vertical aligning. This will create a (visual) baseline above which will display each image. Compatibility is the same as `display: table`, that is IE8+.

CSS:

```
.row {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
.pic {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.pic:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.pic img {
    vertical-align: bottom; /* only needed for removing a few pixel gap between image and paragraph */
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.pic p {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x60/000/fff" alt="ALT">
        <p>Lorem<br>ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x80/000/fff" alt="ALT">
        <p>Lorem</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x20/000/fff" alt="ALT">
        <p>Lorem<br>ipsum<br>trying to break<br>everything</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x40/000/fff" alt="ALT">
        <p>Lorem<br>ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Though this seems to be the best answer so far I still would like more to be handled "automatically". I don't want to have to set the height. The images can have all different heights and I need a dynamic height so that the rows below doesn't get an awkward big gap. I can't set the margin/padding-top either cause the images seems to overlap each other. I guess this is because it's a table and not a block.

Comment: Now that's embarassing... Just remove the height on parent and paragraph and change the `vertical-align: bottom` to `baseline`. http://jsfiddle.net/xWA6d/4/ (also `vertical-align: bottom` to remove a gap if you don't want it)

Answer (score 0):

Make the wrapping div `position: relative;` and then give the images this CSS:

```
#wrapper .img_class {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 20px; /* variable value */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me... [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guitarmanmike/HQB5P/12/) It doesn't run the js in jsfiddle but it works if you copy that to an html file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>images</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var maxHeight;

function getMaxHeight(){
    var imgs=document.getElementsByClassName("bottomAlignedImage");

    if(imgs.length>0){
        maxHeight=imgs[0].height;
        for( var i=1; i<imgs.length; i++){
         var currImg = imgs[i];
            if(currImg.height>maxHeight)
              maxHeight = currImg.height;
              }
        }

}

function applyMarginToImages(){

    var imgs=document.getElementsByClassName("bottomAlignedImage");

    for( var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++){
        var currImg = imgs[i];
        currImg.style.marginTop = maxHeight-currImg.height;
        }
}

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="getMaxHeight();applyMarginToImages();">
<table>
<tr id="imgRow">
    <td><img class="bottomAlignedImage" style="" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x300/000/fff"/></td>
    <td><img class="bottomAlignedImage" style="" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff"/></td>
    <td><img class="bottomAlignedImage" style="" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x150/000/fff"/></td>
</tr>
<tr id="imgTextRow">
<td class="center"><p>Big</p></td>
<td class="center"><p>Small</p></td>
<td class="center"><p>Medium</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ultimate solution is here. It's fully adaptable.

http://jsfiddle.net/v99yf/1/

In this example I used `<p>` but you can use `<div>`